# Transformation matrix from three points in 3-D space

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, transformation

I have three points in $3$-D space, say ${\bf p}_i, i=1,2,3$. A new co-ordinate system, $\{2\}$, is defined such that:

1. The origin is located at the circumcentre, ${\bf p}_0$, of the triangle given by points ${\bf p}_i$.
2. The $x$-axis is in the same direction as the vector ${\bf p}_{10}$, i.e.,  (${\bf p}_1-{\bf p}_0$).
3. The $z$-axis is normal to the plane formed by the points, ${\bf p}_i$.

I wish to find the transformation matrix (rotation matrix and translation vector) so that the initial frame is transformed to the frame $\{2\}$. Also, the circumradius, $\rho$, is required.

I have used the following method to obtain the results:

1. ${\bf a} = {\bf p}_1 - {\bf p}_3$, ${\bf b}={\bf p}_2-{\bf p}_3$
2. $\rho=\frac{\|{\bf a}\|\|{\bf b}\|\|\bf a-b\|}{2\|\bf a\times b\|}$
3. ${\bf p}_0=\frac{(\|{\bf a}\|^2{\bf b}-\|{\bf b}\|^2{\bf a})\times (\bf a \times b)}{2 \|\bf a \times b\|^2}+{\bf p}_3$
4. ${\bf \hat{x}}_2=\frac{{\bf p}_1-{\bf p}_0}{\|{\bf p}_1-{\bf p}_0\|}$
5. ${{\bf \hat{z}}}_2=\frac{{\bf \hat{x}_2}\times ({\bf p}_2-{\bf p}_0)}{\|{\bf \hat{x}_2}\times ({\bf p}_2-{\bf p}_0)\|}$
6. ${{\bf \hat{y}}}_2=\frac{{\bf \hat{z}_2}\times {\bf \hat{x}_2}}{\|{\bf \hat{z}_2}\times {\bf \hat{x}_2}\|}$
7. ${\bf R}= [{{\hat{\bf x}}_2},{{\hat{\bf y}}_2},{{\hat{\bf z}}_2}]$

Questions:

1. It is required that the Rotation matrix, ${\bf R}$, be obtained in closed form. I was expecting a simpler form. However, the end result turns out to be very complicated and is not solvable on paper. Can the problem be solved in a much simpler way?
2. What are the flaws in this method? If the points are collinear, then the algorithm will fail.
3. How can we determine the correctness of the solution?

Comment: I have understood the 2nd formula which comes $a/\sin(A)=\cdots = 2R$. I stopped at your 3rd formula that I have not understood for the main reason that it looks inhomogeneous: you cannot have : "point = vector minus point". It should be "point = vector + point".

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It should have been a plus. However, I did not understand your argument of not holding homogeneity. I imagine points can be represented as vectors. So vector ${\bf p}_3$ is essentially vector from origin to the point. Am I missing something? Is it something to do with vectors being "free" and points are bound to the origin?

Comment: The term "homogeneity" is not to be taken in that sense. I just wanted to say that a vector can only be equated to the **difference** of two points. Th sum of two points $A$ and $B$ is a weighted point $2C$ in barycentric computations.